# Problem while using navigation drawer and bottom navigation bar with different menu

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-bottomnav

The java class in  which  have used both..

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class NavigActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private NavController navController;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navig);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(new int[]{R.id.home, R.id.addNewProduct, R.id.notifications,R.id.user_details,R.id.settings,R.id.help})
                        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                        .build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController,appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration);
    }
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else
          super.onBackPressed();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        int id= menuItem.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.user_details)
        {
            fragment = new UserFragment();
        }
        if(id == R.id.settings)
        {

        }
        if(id == R.id.help)
        {

        }
        if(id== R.id.logout)
        {
            MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
           obj.logout();
           startActivity(new Intent(NavigActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        if(fragment != null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
}
```

It's Layout file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigActivity">




    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:navGraph="@navigation/main" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/nav"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/nav"
            app:menu="@menu/main"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        app:menu="@menu/side_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        ></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

when I am clicking on the user option the menu it does not directs to the fragment, it displays its feature in main page and then those are displayed in every page in the app..
The User Fragment is

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class UserFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And its layout file is

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated..And If anyone can suggest a better way of using navigation drawer and bottom navigation in same app then I would be very grateful to him..